# How to use UUID in a VARCHAR column with Slick?

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have a MySQL 5.7 database with several tables that store UUIDs in columns with a VARCHAR data type. I am trying to convert our code base to use Slick 3.1.1, but I am facing a problem with UUID to String conversions. This is my column definition:

```
def myCol: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("myCol", SqlType("VARCHAR"))
```

When I run queries I get exceptions like this:

```
Got the exception java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xDA\xFD\xDAuOL...' for column 'myCol' at row 1
```

From what I understand, Slick assumes that UUIDs should be stored as binary column types so I tried to implicitly convert to String using:

```
implicit val uuidToString = MappedColumnType.base[UUID, String](_.toString, UUID.fromString)
def myCol: Rep[UUID] = column[UUID]("myCol", SqlType("VARCHAR"))(uuidToString)
```

This works for insertion, but when I select values with `myCol` results come empty. Anyone knows how can I force Slick to use VARCHAR instead of BINARY(16) for the data conversion?

EDIT:

With the implicit this query does not return any results:

```
db.run { table.filter(_.myCol === val)).result }
```

But this one does:

```
db.run { table.result }.map(_.filter(_.myCol == val))
```

EDIT2:

I have a small project with a demo here: https://github.com/nmatpt/slick-uuid-test

Comment: Just a note but you can also store the high/low order bits, since a UUID is just two `long` values (and pair the two columns as a single unique key). If you still want to use strings, you don't need a `VARCHAR` (as a UUID string is always 36 chars, 32 with dashes removed).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You sure about empty values coming from db? I just checked my implementation (in one of the projects, exactly same solution) and it seems to work perfectly. Make sure your physical column (in DB) is actually of type VARCHAR (and not some binary).

EDIT:
OK, the problem that we have is that `UUID` definition as `BINARY` is already included in MySQL profile. Quick (though maybe a little dirty) was of redefining it globally would be like this:

```
package profile

import java.sql.{PreparedStatement, ResultSet}

import slick.ast._
import slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile

object CustomMySqlProfile  extends MySQLProfile {
  import java.util.UUID

  override val columnTypes = new JdbcTypes

  class JdbcTypes extends super.JdbcTypes {
    override val uuidJdbcType = new UUIDJdbcType {
      override def sqlTypeName(sym: Option[FieldSymbol]) = "UUID"
      override def valueToSQLLiteral(value: UUID) = "'" + value + "'"
      override def hasLiteralForm = true

      override def setValue(v: UUID, p: PreparedStatement, idx: Int) = p.setString(idx, toString(v))
      override def getValue(r: ResultSet, idx: Int) = fromString(r.getString(idx))
      override def updateValue(v: UUID, r: ResultSet, idx: Int) = r.updateString(idx, toString(v))

      private def toString(uuid: UUID) = if(uuid != null) uuid.toString else null
      private def fromString(uuidString: String) = if(uuidString != null) UUID.fromString(uuidString) else null
    }
  }
}
```

And then importing it instead of regular `api`:

```
import profile.CustomMySqlProfile.api._
```

**This definitely works - but keep in mind that now UUID would be mapped to string throughout your whole application (instead of default binary).** Basically I needed to override profile only because `UUID` conversion is built in. Normally you would use type mappings.

Similar thing got solved in a similar way here: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1446 (also UUID but for Oracle driver).

Comment: Also what do you mean by: `results come empty`? Exception should be probably thrown if this field would be empty (as you would convert `UUID.fromString` with invalid value).

It may be worth to split mapping into separate functions (one separate function for mapping UUID -> String and one String -> UUID. In the second one you could then add some logging / break points to see what happens.

Comment: First query seems to be good though. Is generated SQL correct? (you can see it by adding following line to your logback.xml -> `<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement" level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: OK, I have an idea. Do you have your implicit mapping in scope in the place where you execute query - this one: `db.run { table.result }.map(_.filter(_.myCol == val))`.

If not - make sure you got it in scope

Comment: Yeah, I realized after writing my comment. I got an idea - try changing your version to this: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.slick/slick_2.11/3.2.0-M1

It's pretty stable BUT what's more important it has new logging level. Add this: `<logger name="slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.parameter" level="DEBUG" />` <- it prints parameters precisely as they are (without question marks)


One of the more relevant changes for you may be this: they changed import in 3.2 `slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._` to `slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile.api._`

Comment: Could you paste your query code together with this implicit?

Comment: Check my answer above. I created very quick PR for you with this change (though I don't have MySQL handy so cannot really check it beyond log information): https://github.com/nmatpt/slick-uuid-test/pull/1

Comment: Thanks, I will test in a moment. I will delete old comments to clean up a bit here.

Comment: Almost works. There is some problem in the conversion because I am getting different uuid's in the select query. The value somehow is different from what is stored in the db.

Comment: OK - tested it on MySQL. Should've done it before. Updated answer above by changing `CustomMySqlProfile`. Task a look at PR - it's passing now both tests.

Comment: Also - similar issue here - solved in the same way on official repo for Slick: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1446

Comment: Yeah, I found that link and I tried to do the same thing you did, but I couldn't get it to work. I also thought there could be a simpler way to do it, but apparently there isn't. Anyway, it's working now. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: FYI to get it work I changed `override def sqlTypeName(sym: Option[FieldSymbol]) = "UUID"` to `override def sqlTypeName(sym: Option[FieldSymbol]) = "VARCHAR"

Answer (score 1):

```
implicit val uuidToString = MappedColumnType.base[UUID, String](_.toString, UUID.fromString)
```

@QP, this also works fine for selects but its essential that this implicit conversion is in scope everywhere you construct queries for VARCHAR columns containing "UUID". Otherwise select with `WHERE` conditions will never match and return empty results.